# Using Angular Masonry in AngularJS?

Tags: css, angularjs, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have a layout like this. I am using `passsy` extension for `angular masonry`.

```
<masonry column-width="200">
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="data in comments">
       <div ng-switch on="data.type">
         <div ng-switch-when="hoots">         
           <article class="hoot_main">
           //content goes here
           //hoot_main is the main class for this div layout
           </article> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch on="data.type">
       <div ng-switch-when="article">         
        <article class="hoot_main">
         //content goes here
         //hoot_main is the main class for this div layout
        </article> 
      </div>
     </div>
      <div ng-switch on="data.type">
        <div ng-switch-when="story">         
          <article class="hoot_main">
           //content goes here
           //hoot_main is the main class for this div layout
          </article> 
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </masonry>
```

Browser is getting hanged whenever I use it. Debugging script with tools says `element.masonry` is not a function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not use masonry? https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

Comment: @mainguy i am integrating passy's angular-masonry. But having some issue. If you have used it. Kindly review my question any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, at the moment I work from my laptop at home and I can't get passy's version running too and can not put my finger on the issue. But this is what I can offer you for now:

I made a very simple directive based on things I've read somewhere:

```
app.directive('masonry', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    controller: function($scope) {
      return $scope.$watch(function(e) {
        $scope.masonry.reloadItems();
        return $scope.masonry.layout();
      });
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var container=elem[0];
      var options='';
      return scope.masonry = new Masonry(container,options);
    }
  };
```

As you can see it does not have a any options by now. When i'm at work on monday i will have a look at my sources on a proper dual screen display and provide you with a better version.
My wife is starting to giving me the looks and I need to put the laptop away now. :-\

You can see [in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/44dPUP9sxlnopMk2VmWB?p=preview) that it kinda works now. Maybe this can help you. In the meantime can you add some of your json data to your question? Have a  nice weekend for now!

Comment: Thanks man!! Well i figured it out. Passy is working now!! . Now need some data optimization for passy data load

Comment: @Creator Can you share how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Passy's angularjs directive working you must include all the files as listed per the index file

Answer (score -4):

I had this error, fixed it by including the original Masonry code. I was also thinking this was a pure angular port.