# AngularJs - Execute Jquery plugin after rest call and DOM change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rest, jstree

I am running AngularJS to manage a WebApp and jQuery plugins manipulating DOM (I have no choice for mixing or not both).

Here is my html

```
<ul jQuery-plugin-directive="{{changeAfterSuccess}}">
    <li ng-repeat="var in varList">
    {{var.attr}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the directive

```
app.directive('jQueryPluginDirective',['$timeout', function (timer) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var myFunctionToExecuteAfterDomMod = function(){
                      //element.myPluginJquery
            }
    }
    };
}]);
```

Here is my controller :

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'anHttpService', function ($scope, documentService) {
        anHttpService.getVarList().success(function (result) {
            $scope.varList = result.var;
            //$scope.changeAfterSuccess = "sthg";
        });
    }]);
```

If I use a timer with 0ms on myFunctionToExecuteAfterDomMod, it doesn't work.

If i use attrs.$observe("jQueryPluginDirective", myFunctionToExecuteAfterDomMod) and change changeAfterSuccess. 
This not work.

The only way I success to use it is to use a timer with more than 10ms. But I don't want to use this ugly solution.

This confirms that myFunctionToExecuteAfterDomMod is called before the {{var.attr}} is changed and that's why it doesn't work...

After searching for a solution for 2hours now, I'm quite desperate, I hope somebody have a good solution.

Bastien

**UPDATE**

I do the thing how I should now. I am sure of it because when I apply simple DOM modification (like css value change) it does work well. The thing is with the plugin jstree it doesn't work if I don't put a 200ms timer... I'll use the "solution" for now and find a way to not use the plugin after.

Comment: Can you please specify order of action? which one is it? Execute RESTApi and then change dom using Jquery? or run Jquery and after wards execute RESTApi?

Comment: Reference to your directive in markup is wrong, should be: `<ul j-query-plugin-directive=`

Comment: Add a $watch to your directive which executes after varList has changed. Look here for a simple example how to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779094/using-angular-masonry-in-angularjs/21801935#21801935

Comment: @Aidin: I want to run the jQUery after RestAPI

Comment: @Brocco: It was just for the example, I modified it, but it's not the problem.

Comment: Can you call the JQuery from within the Sucess() call back of $http?

Comment: @mainguy: Could you explain me a little more ? I don't get how to do in my case ?

Comment: @Aidin: I could, but 
1: It won't work after DOM change.
2: I don't want to put DOM manipulation into controllers

Comment: What do you mean it wont work after the DOM change? Please elaborate. a plunker would help

Comment: Plunker is hard to do because I change $scope.varList on the success of a http.get call.

I mean, when i do this it execute the jQuery before {{var.attr}} has been changed in the DOM

Comment: see my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to pass a variable as a separate parameter:

```
app.directive('jQueryPluginDirective',['$timeout', function (timer) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           data: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var myFunctionToExecuteAfterDomMod = function(){
                      //element.myPluginJquery
            }
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal){
               alert('data changed'); // probably want to use console.log() here instead
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

then your HTML would look like this:

```
<ul jQuery-plugin-directive data="changeAfterSuccess">
```

### UPDATE:

Also, why don't you pass the data and generate html in your directive:

controller HTML:

```
<jQuery-plugin-directive change="{{changeAfterSuccess}}" data="varList"></jQuery-plugin-directive>
```

JS in directive

```
app.directive('jQueryPluginDirective',['$timeout', function (timer) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           data: "=",
           change: "="
        },
        template: "<ul> 
                       <li ng-repeat="var in varList">
                           {{var.attr}}
                       </li>
                   </ul>", // concatenate these lines in to a string
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var myFunctionToExecuteAfterDomMod = function(){
                      //element.myPluginJquery
            }
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal){
               alert('data changed'); // probably want to use console.log() here instead
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I try to do it, but always have 
ReferenceError: test (replacing data of your example) is not defined

Comment: sorry, forgot, data needs to be 'data' (in quotes)

Comment: I don't get why, but template doesn't append its value without diplaying errors.

Comment: If I don't use it, the plugin works but strangly the value in {{}} aren't replace and are shown as {{object.attr}}.

Comment: The only way I manage to make it work is with timer(myFunctionToExecuteAfterDomMod, 200); inside $watch...

Comment: Hi, after a lot of test, I now arrive to the conslusion that this is a problem with the jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Although everything was said by EliteOctagon allready here is a minimal directive to show you how to use a watcher:

```
    app.directive('makered', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        controller: function($scope) {
          return $scope.$watch(function(e) {
            $('.item').css('color', rcolor);
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

Look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9eRBeJgokE0TQw23SJJf?p=preview) how to use it, then try to understand EliteOctagons code. (Cant use ajax in a plunker, so I mocked a scope change)

Comment: Hi! I do understand the code, and I do the thing how I should now. I am sure of it because when I apply simple DOM modification it does work well. The the is with the plugin jstree it doesn't work if I don't put a 200ms timer...